# Is there an online database of acid and basic dissociation constants?

Tags: acid-base, reference-request

Is there an online database of acid and basic dissociation constants, all in one place, free to use?

Comment: Is this possibly what you are looking for? => http://www.csun.edu/~hcchm003/321/Ka.pdf and http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/equilibrium_acids.htm and http://genchem1.chem.okstate.edu/1314F13/Database/ABKs.pdf .... ?

Comment: [Here is a very large table of pKas](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/), measured in DMSO which allows the determination of a much broader range of acidities than measurements in water. Note however that acidities in water are not necessarily the same as acidities in DMSO, as the latter is a polar **non-protic** solvent. For example, $\ce{H2O}$ is approximately $10^{15}$ times more acidic in water than in DMSO (and equivalently, $\ce{OH-}$ is approximately $10^{15}$ times more basic in DMSO than in water).

Comment: To add to my comment above, I have since realized that [the same site](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/organic/index-chem.htm) also has an extensive section for acidities measured in water, [here](http://research.chem.psu.edu/brpgroup/pKa_compilation.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of resources available that provide dissociation constants for acids and bases.  The following are examples:

UC Davis Chemwiki pages [E1: Acid Dissociation Constants at 25°C](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Reference/Reference_Tables/Equilibrium_Constants/E1%3A_Acid_Dissociation_Constants_at_25%C2%B0C) and [E2. Base Dissociation Constants at 25°C](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Reference/Reference_Tables/Equilibrium_Constants/E2._Base_Dissociation_Constants_at_25%C2%B0C) provide many examples.  These are based on information taken from [CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 85th Edition](https://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9780849304859).

The WikiBook [Chemical Principles/Solution Equilibria: Acids and Bases](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chemical_Principles/Solution_Equilibria:_Acids_and_Bases) provides a reasonable database of dissociation constants of acids and bases (Tables 5.3 and 5.4), as well as some further information about how the values are calculated.

The California State University webpage [p-functions for common acids and bases](http://www.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/data-ka.htm), also at 25C, of a series of acids and bases.

Answer (score 1):

The [Evans'](http://evans.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf) and [Bordwell](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/index.htm) $pK_a$ tables provide an excellent source of data for water and DMSO based measurements, particularly for organic compounds.