# Free on-line dissociation constants

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equilibrium, reference-request

Is there a decent on-line source for dissociation constants for acids and bases as CRC alternative?

This chemistry stackexchange old answer no longer has valid links:
[Is there an online database of acid and basic dissociation constants?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/is-there-an-online-database-of-acid-and-basic-dissociation-constants)

I can only find abrupt and and possibly non-reliable links with often missed temperature like these:

- https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/acidity.htm
- https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/strength-of-acids/
- https://infotables.com/chemical-tables/87-dissociation-constants-of-acids-and-bases-inorganic.html
- https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Reference/Reference_Tables/Equilibrium_Constants/E1%3A_Acid_Dissociation_Constants_at_25C
- https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Acids_and_Bases/Monoprotic_Versus_Polyprotic_Acids_And_Bases/Polyprotic_Acids_and_Bases_1
- https://depts.washington.edu/eooptic/links/acidstrength.html
- https://clas.sa.ucsb.edu/staff/Resource%20Folder/Chem109ABC/Acid,%20Base%20Strength/Table%20of%20Acids%20w%20Kas%20and%20pKas.pdf

Thank you.